# gles2 live wallpaper converted to c# (xamarin) complies with error "...mono.android.TypeManager cannot be applied to

Tags: c#, android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, xamarin

I am attempting to write an android live wallpaper using xamarin in c#.

To do so, I converted the GLWallPaperService code found here into c#:
http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/


(jump directly to java implementation here: https://github.com/learnopengles/Learn-OpenGLES-Tutorials/tree/master/android/AndroidOpenGLESLessons/src/com/learnopengles/android/livewallpaper)


Upon compile, I get the error:

> Activate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object[]) in mono.android.TypeManager cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.[redacted].OpenGLES2WallpaperService.OpenGLES2WallpaperService_OpenGLES2Engine,java.lang.Object[])  mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("com.[redacted].OpenGLES2WallpaperService/OpenGLES2Engine, GameUtilClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "com.[redacted].WallpaperServiceUtil.OpenGLES2WallpaperService, GameUtilClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", this, new java.lang.Object[] { OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this });  D:\[redacted]\obj\Debug\android\src\com\[redacted] \wallpaperserviceutil\OpenGLES2WallpaperService.java

Here is my c# implementation... sorry for the length:

```
public abstract class GLWallpaperService : WallpaperService
{
    public class GLEngine : Engine
    {
        private readonly GLWallpaperService outerInstance;

        public GLEngine(GLWallpaperService outerInstance) : base(outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        internal class WallpaperGLSurfaceView : GLSurfaceView
        {
            private readonly GLWallpaperService.GLEngine outerInstance;
            ISurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;

            internal WallpaperGLSurfaceView(GLWallpaperService.GLEngine outerInstance, Context context, ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
                : base(context)
            {
                this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
                _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            }

            public override ISurfaceHolder Holder
            {
                get
                {
                    return _surfaceHolder;
                }
            }

            public virtual void OnDestroy()
            {
                base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
            }
        }

        private WallpaperGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
        private bool rendererHasBeenSet;

        public override void OnCreate(ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
        {
            base.OnCreate(surfaceHolder);

            glSurfaceView = new WallpaperGLSurfaceView(this, outerInstance, surfaceHolder);
        }

        public override void OnVisibilityChanged(bool visible)
        {
            base.OnVisibilityChanged(visible);

            if (rendererHasBeenSet)
            {
                if (visible)
                {
                    glSurfaceView.OnResume();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!IsPreview)
                    {
                        glSurfaceView.OnPause();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            glSurfaceView.OnDestroy();
        }

        protected internal virtual Android.Opengl.GLSurfaceView.IRenderer NewRenderer//was just Renderer
        {
            set
            {
                glSurfaceView.SetRenderer(value);
                rendererHasBeenSet = true;
            }
        }

        protected internal virtual int EGLContextClientVersion
        {
            set
            {
                glSurfaceView.SetEGLContextClientVersion(value);
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class OpenGLES2WallpaperService : GLWallpaperService
{
    public override Engine OnCreateEngine()
    {
        return new OpenGLES2Engine(this);
    }

    internal class OpenGLES2Engine : GLWallpaperService.GLEngine
    {
        private readonly OpenGLES2WallpaperService outerInstance;

        public OpenGLES2Engine(OpenGLES2WallpaperService outerInstance)
            : base(outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
        {
            base.OnCreate(surfaceHolder);

            // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
            //JAVA TO C# CONVERTER WARNING: The original Java variable was marked 'final':
            //ORIGINAL LINE: final android.app.ActivityManager activityManager = (android.app.ActivityManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)outerInstance.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
            //JAVA TO C# CONVERTER WARNING: The original Java variable was marked 'final':
            //ORIGINAL LINE: final android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
            ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.DeviceConfigurationInfo;
            //JAVA TO C# CONVERTER WARNING: The original Java variable was marked 'final':
            //ORIGINAL LINE: final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
            bool supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.ReqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

            if (supportsEs2)
            {
                // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
                EGLContextClientVersion = 2;

                // Set the renderer to our user-defined renderer.
                NewRenderer = outerInstance.NewRenderer;//was just Renderer
            }
            else
            {
                // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
                // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    internal abstract Android.Opengl.GLSurfaceView.IRenderer NewRenderer { get; }
}

public class LessonThreeWallpaperService : OpenGLES2WallpaperService
{
    internal override Android.Opengl.GLSurfaceView.IRenderer NewRenderer
    {
        get
        {
            return new LessonThreeRenderer(); // is a GLSurfaceView.IRenderer
        }
    }
}
```

I am targeting version sdk version 8 and using Visual Studio 2012.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in our Android Callable Wrapper generator code: we don't properly support "intermediate" non-static inner classes from C#. Specifically, `GLWallpaperService.Engine` is generated properly, but `OpenGLES2WallpaperService.OpenGLES2Engine` is not.

Please file a bug at [bugzilla.xamarin.com](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com).